# What does DataType in sequelize do? Why pass it in the argument and ran without defining it?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I saw this tutorial but there are few things I don't understand.

The link to the tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZMwg5z5VGk&t=872s

This creates the model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => 
sequelize.define('User', {

    email:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
})
```

//this imports the model

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config =  require('../config/config')

const db = {}
var a = ''

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
config.db.database,
config.db.user,
config.db.password,
config.db.options
)

fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter((file) => 
file !== 'index.js'
).forEach((file) => 
{

const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
db[model.name] = model

})

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;


module.exports = db;
```

where did the DataTypes come from?
It was not imported from the module
Why do I need to pass it as an Argument?

And also I am having trouble understanding the lines

```
const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
db[model.name] = model
```

Comment: You need to provide more context for the first piece of code. Where is it defined and where is it used? Or provide a link to the tutorial you saw

Comment: Updated the link to the tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call

```
var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
```

an `import` function of sequelize is called where it loads the models. You can look at the code [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/sequelize.js#L395)

The code says `this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);`, so we know how it gets the `DataTypes`

You can also validate and understand more if you look at the callstack and put the breakpoint at `sequelize.define` or better at `const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))` and start digging deep. Below is the snapshot on how the callstack looks like

[image: call stack]

Comment: I would suggest you also look at [sequelize cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) which would create `model/index.js` on its own and also brings in lots of helpers which can make life easier when working with sequelize